# Umbrella header 'GoogleMobileAds.h' not found and Could not build module 'GoogleMobileAds'

Tags: ios, xcode, parsing

I am building xcode project of unity game with ads from unity 5.2 on windows. Then compiling it in macbook with Xcode 8 but following errors are coming.

Parse Issue
Umbrella header 'GoogleMobileAds' not found

Could not build module 'GoogleMobileAds'

I have put unzipped googelmobilesdkios in Unity 3D Windows with plugin. Also I have added GoogleMobileAds framework in xcode but still not recognizing it.

I have also linked C and Objective-C modules.

Please tell me correct answer?

Comment: see this https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/issues/68

Comment: In code using @import GoogleMobileAds; instead of #include GoogleMobilesads.h;    And my problem not yet solved......

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem ? I have the same problem now